# Is it possible to map same json field to multiple Java objects with different data types

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have a situation where I need to map same JSON field to multiple Java objects with different datatypes, So that when certain condition is true, I will be mapping the field with decimal value, and if condition is false the field will be mapped with integer value.

POJO definitions something like below:

```
@JsonProperty("purchasedQty")
private int purchasedQty

@JsonProperty("purchasedQty")
private double purchasedQty_decimal
```

expected implementation:

```
true
{
"purchasedQty" : 1.0;
}

else
{
"purchasedQty" : 1;
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve the expected implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there might be several ways to achieve this.

First, have synthetic setter to update all fields related to certain property.

```
    @JsonProperty("purchasedQty")
    public void setPurchasedQtyMultiType(Number value) {
        this.purchasedQty = value.intValue();
        this.purchasedQty_decimal = value.doubleValue();
    }
```

Second, you may have custom deserialiser that explcitly sets all the required fields.

Third, you may have different classes with different field types for each scenario and choose to deserialise explicitly to one of them.

There also might be other ways.